# get text from listview item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I have a `listview` that stores the result of speech recognition:

```
voice_list.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, 
    Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) 
    { 
        Toast.MakeText(this, "test", ToastLength.Long).Show(); 
    };
```

How I can get the text in the item? For example, when I say "no", it recognizes (now, know, you know....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemClickEventArgs` you have contain a couple of nice properties you can use, one of them is especially very useful `Position`. This gives you the `Position` in the `ListView` of the item you clicked, which corresponds to the same position of the item in your dataset you have passed to the `Adapter` you are using.

So in your `ItemClick` event handler you can do:

```
var item = _adapter.GetItem(args.Position);
```

You will probably have to cast the item afterwards.

Comment: I get this error:

Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetItem' and no extension method 'GetItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\OMed\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Test_Recognition_translation\Test_Recognition_translation\Activity1.cs 55 44 Test_Recognition_translation

Comment: It is because you are not calling it on your `Adapter` instance and trying to call `GetItem` on an `IList`.

Comment: it s working now :D, thank YOU Sir,
Can you please answer on this quetion pleaaase :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556616/speech-recognition-android-application-c