# speech recognition android application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

my application recognises speech when I press speak button and print results on listview, and when i click on the the result I want it print it on toast....

the problem is when i click the button again it prints the new text and also the old text, for example in the first time i get  : (no ,now, know) I click no and it shows "now",
the second time it gives (google, good, Google) I press good and it prints "now" then "good"

I think it remembers the whole listview, can you please help me to solve this problem, this is the code:

```
if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
{
    IList<System.String> matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
    voice_list.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<System.String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, matches);
    voice_list.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = matches[e.Position];

        string TextToTranslate = t.ToString();

        Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, TextToTranslate , Android.Widget.ToastLength.Long).Show();

    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're adding an eventhandler everytime you're handling the result.
So the 2nd time you're handling the voice result adds another eventhandler to the ItemClick event. That will result in 2 events handlers when you click an item. 
Try to move this part. But also keep in mind that if you move it to OnStart this will be called also when you're coming back from another screen.

Not really sure why you get the first one displayed again, but maybe you also have to trigger NotifyDataSetChanged to the Adapter after you've changed it.

I personally prefer to create a new class for the adapter, extended from BaseAdapter, where you will handle the list with items and itemsclicked. (example: [Custom ListAdapter for your ListView](http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview/))